# What's the meaning of すます in 耳をすませば?

Tags: translation, meaning, set-phrases, idioms

What's the meaning of すます in 耳をすませば?

How would you translate this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`すます` is `澄ます` without the kanji, and it means "to clear, to purify".

`耳をすます【みみをすます】`is a set phrase, listed in the dictionary in its complete form, meaning to listen carefully.

You can think of `すます`, then, in this context, as meaning to clear out your ears so as to listen better.

Comment: Didn't realize it was an idiom. I think I'll stop trying to deconstruct it.

Comment: Actually, the relevant sense of `すます` that is the origin of this idiom is `澄ます` 'purify'. So the non-idiomatic translation is 'purify the ear'.

Comment: sawa: Okay, I'll trust you on that and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

It is difficult to translate `すます` alone in this context. `耳をすます` is an idiom meaning 'pay attention to any slight sound'

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context, it's the title of a movie. Thanks for commenting on Dave's answer. Going from to complete -> completely kinda bugged me.

Comment: @Louis No problem. By context, I just meant it would not be useful to give a non-idiomatic translation. But it turned out it may have been. What you gave was sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above 耳をすます is an idiom that means 'to listen carefully'. If we translate literally there is a kanji for 'ears' - '耳' and a verb 'すます' which means - 'to clear' - so if we combine these it's - 'to clear ears' which is the same as 'to listen carefully'.

As for translation of 耳をすませば, it seems that すませば is a form of a verb to include 'if'. So I would translate it as 'if you/someone listen carefully' or something of that sort.